# How to removed canvas element event listeners

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6, salesforce, lwc

In canvas I draw line,rectange,triangle. canvas listener **mousedown** add two event listeners **mousemove,mouseup**. In listener mouseup event want to remove listeners **mousemove,mouseup**.

Add listener works, but removed listener not work.

**Listner add on mousedown event:**

```
this.appCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
            this.onMouseDown(e);
        });

    onMouseDown(e) {
        this.savedImage = this.appContext.getImageData( 0,0,this.appContext.canvas.width,
            this.appContext.canvas.height
        );

        this.appCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
            this.onMouseMove(e);
        });
        this.template.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
            this.onMouseUp(e);
        });
    }
```

**Remove listener on mouseup event**

```
onMouseUp(e) {      
    this.appCanvas.removeEventListener( "mousemove",(e) => {this.onMouseMove(e);},false );
    this.template.removeEventListener("mouseup",(e) => {this.onMouseUp(e);},false);
}
```

**listener removed not work, still canvas mousemove and mouseup event work** . In mouseup event want to removed listeners from the canvas element.

Comment: You have to call `.removeEventListener()` with the exact same function you've used for `.addEventListener()` -> Don't use an anonymous function.

Comment: @ Andreas, are you suggest using the bind function like this.onMouseMove.bind(this) instead of arrow function.

Comment: As I've said. Use a named function. How you then achieve the the effect you want (with `this`) is a matter of how your function looks like and is therefor up to you.

Comment: @ Andreas,used named function not work.toadd use this syntax 
 this.appCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove.bind(this)); to removed used this.appCanvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove.bind(this), false);  show error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of undefined